# Is it possible to let ansible print each statement?

Tags: docker, ansible, devops

For example, I have this ansible task, which is to run DockerUI container.

`- name: DockerUI is running
  docker:
    image: uifd/ui-for-docker
    name: dockerui
    ports: 9000:9000
    privileged: yes
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  tags: [docker]`

Is it possible to see what exactly docker command did this ansible task invoke? Like `docker run ...`

Answer (score 2):

The Ansible Docker modules don't execute `docker` command lines.  They use the [Docker HTTP API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/) to accomplish their work, via the [docker-py](https://github.com/docker/docker-py) python module.

The best way to figure out what the module is doing is probably by watching the docker daemon logs, or by inspecting the module source.